# Django, Python Type Error metaclass conflict:

Tags: python, html, django, calendar

Im utilizng Django to build an HTMLCalendar with python, I keep running into the same type errors and I do not know what to do when I receive this type error unfortunately while the argument is HTMLCalender inside of Contest Calendar class, the only error ill receive is that it takes 3 arguments instead of one, But I cant put in another argument without getting a type error metaclass conflict.

```
from calendar import HTMLCalendar 
from calendar import monthrange

class ContestCalendar(HTMLCalendar):

def __init__(self, pContestEvents):
    super(ContestCalendar, self).__init__()
    self.contest_events = self.group_by_day(pContestEvents)

def formatday(self, day, weekday):
    if day != 0:
        cssclass = self.cssclasses[weekday]
        if date.today() == date(self.year, self.month, day):
            cssclass += ' today'
        if day in self.contest_events:
            cssclass += ' filled'
            body = []
            for contest in self.contest_events[day]:
                body.append('<a href="%s">' % contest.get_absolute_url())
                body.append(esc(contest.contest.name))
                body.append('</a><br/>')
            return self.day_cell(cssclass, '<div class="dayNumber">%d</div> %s' % (day, ''.join(body)))
        return self.day_cell(cssclass, '<div class="dayNumber">%d</div>' % day)
    return self.day_cell('noday', '&nbsp;')

def formatmonth(self, year, month):
    self.year, self.month = year, month
    return super(ContestCalendar, self).formatmonth(year, month)

def group_by_day(self, pContestEvents):
    field = lambda contest: contest.date_of_event.day
    return dict(
        [(day, list(items)) for day, items in groupby(pContestEvents, field)]
    )

def day_cell(self, cssclass, body):
    return '<td class="%s">%s</td>' % (cssclass, body)
```

Comment: Please paste your full exception and backtrace

Comment: is `contest.contest.name` above OK?